# Selectively populating a pandas column depending if the value in a different column falls into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with names of small geographic areas in one column. I have developed a set of rules that define which of these areas fall into what larger regions. Since every rule is a condition, I have tried using np.select, but I keep getting a mistake.

This is what I have tried:

```
Okanagan_and_Kootenays = ['Columbia-Shuswap','Central Okanagan', 'North Okanagan', 'Okanagan-Similkameen', 'East Kootenay', 'Kootenay Boundary','Central Kootenay' ]

conditions = [(main_file['long_name'] == Okanagan_and_Kootenays)]
choices = 'Okanagan_and_Kootenays'

main_file['_area_large'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

And I get the following error every time:

`ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 1412 vs 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) your choices should be an iterable (list) of the same length as the `conditions` list:

```
Okanagan_and_Kootenays = ['Columbia-Shuswap','Central Okanagan', 'North Okanagan',
                          'Okanagan-Similkameen', 'East Kootenay', 'Kootenay Boundary',
                          'Central Kootenay' ]

conditions = [(main_file['long_name'].isin(Okanagan_and_Kootenays))]
choices = ['Okanagan_and_Kootenays']

main_file['_area_large'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `np.select` is the most efficient way in this case. What are you planning to do if you have many large areas? A loop is going to be really slow.

You might consider the following approach:

```
import pandas as pd

dct = {"area1": ["town1", "town2", "town3"],
       "area2": ["town4", "town5", "town6", "town7"]}

df = pd.DataFrame({"town": sum([dct[k] for k,v
                                in dct.items()],
                               [])})

inv_dct = {}
for k, vs in dct.items():
    for v in vs:
        inv_dct[v] = k

df["area"] = df["town"].map(inv_dct)
```